# what would be the best approach in creating a full flash website

Tags: flash, animation, web, 3d, flash-cs4

I see all this heavy Flash/3D websites and it's making me wonder how do they build it having to load it so fast. Let me know your thoughts on what/how would be the best practice or approach on this.

Comment: The best approach to making a website entirely out of Flash is almost always "don't". There are few situations in which it's desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load pieces as they are needed. Also, make the pieces as lightweight as possible. Go to the server for "heavy" content as required (i.e., bitmapped data, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Robusto is right on, loading pieces as needed is essential. A quality full flash site is tricky to pull off unless you do it right from the beginning. See example:

http://www.2advancedstudios.com/